# Jquery and sharepoint, trying to get a value from a field, and put it into another field

Tags: jquery, sharepoint-2010

So I have an odd issue, I am trying to get the value from a text field called name and put it into another field called title. It isn't working at all.

Basically, I have been doing this:
The field value that I am using I got from the id part of the field.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://secureteams.app.aexp.com/sites/fiucmc/SiteAssets/jquery-3.1.0.min.js">
    // getting the field
     var email = $("#FileLeafRef_8553196d-ec8d-4564-9861-3dbe931050c8_$onetidIOFile").val();

    // setting the value
    $("#Title_fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247_$TextField").val( email );

   </script>
```

Granted I am not the best at JQuery, I really don't think this should be that hard.

Comment: What's the context here? When does this code run, and what does the relevant HTML look like at that point?

Comment: So this code is in a content editor webpart that is run whenever a user needs to upload a document to SharePoint. The title field is gotten from the document that the user is uploading automatically, so I am just trying to get the value of that field and add it to the name field. As far as the HTML goes, not really sure what you are asking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
var email = $("input[title='FileLeafRef']").val();
$("input[title='Title']").val( email );
```

should work just fine if FileLeafRef is a field title. But you need to add this script to the Document Upload form, because from your answer to the Thriggle question I am not sure that the code runs in the right place.

Comment: So I found another way to do it using a sharepoint designer workflow. But, just fyi... your code didn't work, and my code is running in the correct place, I put an alert("Hello World") in it and it came up. Thanks for trying to help.

Comment: Mike, no one would write you the code that works until you at least provide filed names and types :) this was just an example that you should have adjusted to your realities..

Answer (score 0):

Finally I've found the solution!
It was based on this web site: [Setting value to TextBox field](http://hacksharepoint.blogspot.com.br/2012/10/how-to-setting-values-of-infopath.html)

Important steps you must follow:

1. Go to the list settings > Advanced Settings > Show form in dialog (set false);
2. Return to the list and click to add a new item;
3. At this point, click to edit the page and then add a Script WebPart
4. Now just copy and paste the following code (**you have to add the id of your form, I'm just using an example**)

```html
<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript' src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
 $.ajax(
 {
  url: "http://yourSharepointSite/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetMyProperties?$select=Email",
  method: "GET",
  headers: 
  {
   "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
  },
  
  success: function (data)
  {
   var result = data.d;
   var userMail= result.Email;

                        var textBoxCurrentUserEmail = $("#ctl00_ctl33_g_58328422_c761_4475_a673_5c3f263a5dab_FormControl0_V1_I1_T3");
                        var textBoxIsAuthor = $("#ctl00_ctl33_g_58328422_c761_4475_a673_5c3f263a5dab_FormControl0_V1_I1_T4");

                        textBoxCurrentUserEmail .val(userMail);
                        textBoxCurrentUserEmail .focus();
                        textBoxIsAuthor .focus();
   window.console && console.log(userMail);
  },
  
  error: function (err)
  {
   alert(JSON.stringify(err));
  }
 });
});
</script>
```

**Please, don't forget to use the .focus() on your element, because this is going to show the new inserted data!**

To conclude, afterward you can set the list to show as dialog mode!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is with the $ which are included as part of the field names. jQuery interprets them as the start of a different variable (I think) and so does not address the field you expect. The solution I found was to pattern match the name which only works on small forms where there is no conflict in the names of the columns and of course you need to consider what might happen in the future if the form develops further.

Regardless, if you wanted to try it I think the following would work:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://secureteams.app.aexp.com/sites/fiucmc/SiteAssets/jquery-3.1.0.min.js">
// getting the field
 var email = $('input[id^="FileLeafRef"]').val();

// setting the value
$('input[id^="Title"]').val( email );
```